# Expectation on double-click

Tags: tables, checkboxes, click

See the below UI mock-up for a standalone PC application with the following fixed requirements:

- Selecting an item should show its description below the table
- The user can check multiple items to buy

---

[image: Table of checkboxes with item labels]

---

What is the expectation when a user **double-clicks** an item in the table?

1. Nothing happens
2. Item is selected, but check-box remains unchanged
3. Item's checkbox is toggled, but the selection remains unchanged (not sure if even possible)
4. Item is selected and check-box is toggled

Comment: what you want to achieve? When user double clicks do you want to retain checked status? or you want to reset it?

Comment: Adding to NB4, have your users requested any further functionality? What are the UX advantages to providing a double click? To add, given the requirements listed, a checkbox would change state and reapply the original state, unless you trapped the double click, the line in the grid do the same, again, unless you wired up some additional functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go with option **2**.

**Item is selected, but check box remains unchanged**

This type of behavior is followed in web for reference you can check **G-mail**

Comment: Forgot to mention this is not a web application. It is a standalone PC app. Would this additional information change your answer?

Answer (score 3):

The way you currently have wireframed, since the checkboxes are separated, I would assume I can only toggle the checkbox by clicking the actual checkbox. If I were to click on the item itself, I would assume that a description appears on the first click, and disappears on the second click.

Personally, I wouldn't even think to double-click because it isn't a folder-like object.

Answer (score 1):

Probably I'd expect to select the row clicking on the label and checking/unchecking by clicking on the checkbox area.

If there are more detailed infos about the selected element I would explicitate this opportunity also because the checkbox path is strong, I would not expect for other informations shown by clicking on the single row out of the checkbox area.

Answer (score 1):

In a desktop application, I usually expect double-clicking a list item to perform the default action associated with the selection, like it does in the Open File dialog in Windows and macOS, for example.

In this case, I assume there's a "Buy" button or similar associated with the list... so I'd expect double-click to be a shortcut for clicking the Buy button.

That said, users are so used to *not* double-clicking these days, due to the rise of touchscreen UIs, that any action may be unexpected or surprising, so it may be safer just to do nothing at all.